# Find most recent date in multiple data.frame objects of unequal sizes in R

Tags: r, loops, max

I have multiple `data.frame` objects of unequal lengths. I would like to find the most recent date in all of them and store the data somewhere.

Here is an example of hopefully reproducible code to illustrate what I would like (with comments and sources). This gives 7 `data.frame` objects of variable lengths:

```
library(quantmod)

# Load ticker data from 2020-01-01 till 2021-02-02
tickers <- c("NKLA", "MPNGF", "RMO", "JD", "COIN")
getSymbols.yahoo(tickers, auto.assign = TRUE, env = globalenv(), from = "2020-01-01", to = "2021-02-02")

# Load ticker data from 2020-01-01 till yesterday (if not weekend or holiday)
tickers2 <- c("IBM", "AAPL", "MRNA")
getSymbols.yahoo(tickers2, auto.assign = TRUE, env = globalenv(), from = "2020-01-01")

# Close all Internet connections as a precaution
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/52758758/2950721
closeAllConnections()

# Find xts objects
xtsObjects <- names(which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.xts))))

# Convert xts to data.frame
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/69246047/2950721
for (i in seq_along(xtsObjects)) {
  assign(xtsObjects[i], fortify.zoo(get(xtsObjects[i])))
}

# 1st column name from Index to Date
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/69292036/2950721
for (i in seq_along(xtsObjects)) {
  tmp <- get(xtsObjects[i])
  colnames(tmp)[colnames(tmp) == "Index"] <- "Date"
  assign(xtsObjects[i], tmp)
}
remove(tmp)
```

Individually retreive the dates is pretty straightforward:

```
max(AAPL$Date)
max(IBM$Date)
max(JD$Date)
max(MPNGF$Date)
max(MRNA$Date)
max(NKLA$Date)
max(RMO$Date)
```

But when I try the following codes none of them would render or, better yet, store the most recent dates with corresponding origine (i.e., ticker):

```
dataframeObjects <- names(which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.data.frame))))

# Tentative 1    
for (i in seq_along(dataframeObjects)) {
  mostRecentDates <- max(dataframeObjects[i]$Date)
}

# Tentative 2
for (i in 1:length(dataframeObjects)) {
  mostRecentDates <- max(dataframeObjects[i]["Date"])
}
```

Both tentatives give a `[1]NA` when invoking variable `mostRecentDates`.

**Important**: In the final code there won't be any `tickers` and `tickers2` variables. There will be a certain quantity of `data.frame` objects that will be loaded locally and it is those that will be searched for the last date available.

My question:

- What code is needed in order to store the most recent dates of all `data.frame` objects (if possible by invoking `dataframeObjects`, but not `tickers` and `tickers2`)?

Thanks in advance.

---

Systems used:

- R version: 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
- RStudio version: 1.4.1717
- OS: macOS Catalina version 10.15.7 and macOS Big Sur version 11.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may get the objects from `intersect` of object names in `ls` and the `ticker` objects, use `mget` to get the value of objects in a `list`, loop over the `list` with `lapply`, extract the 'Date' column and get the `max`

```
do.call(c, lapply(mget(intersect(c(tickers, tickers2), ls())), 
       function(x) max(x$Date)))
```

-output

```
   NKLA        MPNGF          RMO           JD          IBM         AAPL         MRNA 
"2021-02-01" "2021-02-01" "2021-02-01" "2021-02-01" "2021-09-28" "2021-09-28" "2021-09-28"
```

#### Update

If the objects in the `ls()` are only from the one created with dataframeObjects, objects, then do

```
do.call(c, lapply(mget(dataframeObjects), function(x) max(x$Date)))
```

---

In the OP's code, the `dataframeObjects` are just names of objects.  We need `get` in the loop to return the value

```
# // in case there are other data.frame objects as well, get the intersect
nm1 <- intersect(dataframeObjects, c(tickers, tickers2))
# // create a `list` to store the output
out <- vector('list', length(nm1))
names(out) <- nm1
for(i in seq_along(nm1)) {
   out[[i]] <- max(get(nm1[i])$Date)
}
```

-output

```
> out
$RMO
[1] "2021-02-01"

$NKLA
[1] "2021-02-01"

$JD
[1] "2021-02-01"

$AAPL
[1] "2021-09-28"

$IBM
[1] "2021-09-28"

$MRNA
[1] "2021-09-28"

$MPNGF
[1] "2021-02-01"
```

Comment: Thanks for the code Akrun. However, what I would have liked is something that does not involve using variables ```tickers``` and ```tickers2```. What I gave was an example. In fact there will be the ```dataframeObjects <- names(which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.data.frame))))``` line. In other words I wanted to invoke the ```dataframeObjects``` variable.

Comment: @pdeli The issue with `is.data.frame`  on .`GlobalEnv` is that if you have already created another data.frame objects unrelated to the tickers, it will also be found.  Instead you may create a new env and put all these objects created there

Comment: Understood. However, in the code where I am going to use the solution I am seeking here, ```data.frame``` objects are loaded locally and those are the ones that will need an update. Those that will be downloaded from the Internet will automatically be up-to-date. Also I am very careful not to create any ```data.frame``` objects before the updates are done. In light of this info, how should your code be tweaked in order to invoke only ```is.data.frame``` and avoid invoking variables ```tickers``` and ```tickers2```?

Comment: @pdeli IN that case, just change the code to `do.call(c, lapply(mget(ls()), 
       function(x) max(x$Date)))`

Comment: Excellent, works perfectly! You mind updating your answer please?

Comment: @pdeli updated the post

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but your solution worked and now it doesn't anymore. When I run ```do.call(c, lapply(mget(ls()), function(x) max(x$Date)))``` it gives me an ```Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors```. Any ideas?

Comment: @pdeli It is because you haven't converted to xts objects back to data.frame.  i.e. in your previous code, you used `fortify.zoo` for conversion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237710/discussion-between-pdeli-and-akrun).

Comment: @pdeli Have you tried the step `for (i in seq_along(xtsObjects)) {
  assign(xtsObjects[i], fortify.zoo(get(xtsObjects[i])))
}`

Comment: For completion's sake the piece of code that finally worked for me based on akrun's answers and the initial question: ```do.call(c, lapply(mget(dataframeObjects), function(x) max(x$Date)))```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to store the `xts` objects in another `environment` than the global one, that makes it much easier to handle them. We can turn that environment into a list and then we can iterate over that list with `purrr::map()` or `base::lapply()`.

Here is what that can look like for your example.

```
library(quantmod)
library(tidyverse)
sym_env <- new.env()

tickers <- c("NKLA", "MPNGF", "RMO", "JD", "COIN")
getSymbols.yahoo(tickers, auto.assign = TRUE, env = sym_env, from = "2020-01-01", to = "2021-02-02")

tickers2 <- c("IBM", "AAPL", "MRNA")
getSymbols.yahoo(tickers2, auto.assign = TRUE, env = sym_env, from = "2020-01-01")

closeAllConnections()

as.list(sym_env) |> 
  map(fortify.zoo) |> 
  map(\(x) rename(x, Date=Index)) |> 
  map(\(x) max(x$Date))
```

Returns:

```
$RMO
[1] "2021-02-01"

$NKLA
[1] "2021-02-01"

$JD
[1] "2021-02-01"

$AAPL
[1] "2021-09-28"

$IBM
[1] "2021-09-28"

$MRNA
[1] "2021-09-28"

$MPNGF
[1] "2021-02-01"
```

In general, it is advisable to organize data objects that are supposed to be processed with the same function(s) in a `list` instead of having them mixed into the global environment. Therefore you should choose a method for obtaining the data that returns a `list`.

You could use any other strategy to obtain a list of xts objects and then feed that in to the chain of `purrr::map()` commands.

```
list_of_xts_objects |> 
  map(fortify.zoo) |> 
  map(\(x) rename(x, Date=Index)) |> 
  map(\(x) max(x$Date))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Till. Would it be possible to leave the ```data.frame``` objects and the ```as.list``` object in the current environment or is it compulsory to create a new one?

Comment: No, it is not compulsory. As long as you have a list object that contains all xts objects you can use this. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. To clarify, this is the sequence in which things would happen: 1. Load locally all existing ```data.frame``` objects (in which previously downloaded tickers are, thus probably not up-to-date) in ```.GlobalEnv```; 2. Scan all the loaded ```data.frame``` objects for last date (here is where the present code would be inserted); 3. Update all ```data.frame``` objects which most recent date is older than yesterday. Knowing this, how could your code be tweaked so that it scans ```data.frame``` objects instead of ```xts``` objects from ```.GlobalEnv```?

Comment: Maybe I should add that under point 1. ```data.frame``` objects already have the ```Index``` columns renamed to ```Date```.